# Command line tool to inline css import statements and resolve relative url references

Tags: css, import, minify

I have a main css file containing a number of import statements to various libraries, for example.

main.css content:

```
@import "libs/abc/abc.css";
@import "libs/xyz-1.2.5/css/xyz.css";
```

The libraries are self contained and link to images within their own relative directory structure - which could have quite a different organisation from one another.

libs/abc/abc.css example content:

```
.myclass1 { background-image:url(image1.png); }
```

libs/xyz-1.2.5/css/xyz.css example content:

```
.myclass2 { background-image:url(../img/image1.png); }
```

In my development environment I would use main.css and then any issues can be traced back to source files. For my release build I would like to take main.css and inline (ie. expand/merge/concat/combine) each of the imports statements while resolving (remapping/rewriting) the relative url() references within it (as the browser effectively  does), to create main.all.css which would be minified to remove comments, etc.. giving main.min.css which is used in the end-user environment.

ie. main.all.css content should look something like this:

```
.myclass1 { background-image:url(libs/abc/image1.png); }
.myclass2 { background-image:url(libs/xyz-1.2.5/img/image1.png); }
```

I am looking for a command line tool to do this, but after an afternoon of searching I haven't been able to turn anything up - no CLI tools, only modules for platforms. I was hoping for something like YUI Compressor which I currently use for minification.

LESS is the closest tool I have found, but to get it to inline it appears that I need to add a directive to the import statement as below, but this of course breaks the main.css file in the browser. (I have tested and this is the case)

ie. LESS appears to require:

```
@import (inline) "libs/abc/abc.css";
```

Edit 1: Just to be clear, I don't want to modify/move or duplicate any files or folders under the /libs folder, just link to these 3rd party modules as they are.

Comment: Just found this tool "CSS Join" [link](https://github.com/suisho/cssjoin) and it seems to do exactly what I am asking for, but are there any others out there?